# I am an 8 letter word. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, letters

> I am a 8 letter word.
>
> 1st and 2nd are the riddle creator.
>
> 3rd, 4th and 5th are a span of time.
>
> 6th, 7th and 8th are a PC program about privacy.

Who am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am a 8 letter word.

> Operator

1st and 2nd are the riddle creator.

> OP

3rd, 4th and 5th are a span of time

> Era is a time period.

6th, 7th and 8th are a PC program about secrecy

> [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/)

Comment: oh IAmInPLS i expected fewer time for you .. jk good job!